# C: User deletes printf()?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, printf

I am using Libxlsxwriter library because I want my results to be exported in Excel Sheet. I am compiling like this:

`gcc name.c -o name -static-libgcc -std=c99 -lxlsxwriter -lz`

This is a test code that illustrates the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "xlsxwriter.h"

int main()
{
    printf("->please insert a text: ");
    char string[100];
    scanf("%s", &string);
    printf("->Your text is %s\n", string);
    printf("->Thank you! Bye");
    getchar();
    getchar();  
    return 0;
}
```

I compile as above and follow these steps:

1) Run the program:

-> please insert a text:

2) Write "Hello there!" (Do not press enter)

-> please insert a text: Hello there!

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrVym.jpg

3) I press left arrow key three times (for example). Cursor goes beneath 'r'

4) Press and hold backspace

-> please inser`______________`here! (*without the dashes. It is just a visualization to show that it is an empty space there*)

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nrw2.jpg

I did a test and removed Libxlsxlibrary so Devc++ could compile it.
The same problem did not appear!

Does this have to do with compiling? Is it possible to fix that somehow?

Comment: `scanf("%s", &string);` ==> `scanf("%99s", string);`

Comment: Err, what is the problem?